# Relationship in ER diagram

Tags: mysql, database-design, azure-sql-database, data

[image: ER diagram]I have this ER diagram assignment for a sport club. I have shown different entities. But I have an entity for staff and then I have entities like instructors, admin, managers, coach. I have be to find relationships for them all except ‘staff’. For example i there’s relationship between instructor and classes, coach and team, but I find it difficult to relate the entity staff. I was trying to relate all the specialized form staff to the staff entity but it doesn’t seem to make sense, so I tried to use a generalization relationship to connect coach, admin, instructor and manager entities to staff entity(I don’t know if this is right though).

This makes staff entity a parent entity, but my main question is, is it possible for a parent entity not to have a relationship while its specialized entity has relationships.

Comment: It might be better to show the diagram

Comment: Can't judge a schema without seeing some of the queries to access it.